# Loading a prolog file with arguments from windows command line

Tags: windows, prolog, swi-prolog

I am currently learning Prolog using SWI Prolog.  I am able to start prolog with a script file and argument in Linux with the following code:

```
swipl -s logic1.pl folder1
```

This starts prolog, loads the .pl file and reads the "folder1" argument.

When I have tried to do the same on my Windows 7 machine via cmd the argument "folder1" doesn't seem to be recognised.  I have been launching SWI Prolog with the following command in cmd:

```
swipl -s logic1.pl folder1
```

SWI Prolog opens, but the prolog file checks that the correct arguments have been provided and then throws an error message telling me that I need to include the folder1 argument and then closes prolog.

Can anyone tell me how to launch SWI Prolog with the file arguments correctly?

Thanks

Comment: Can you show the code you have in `logic1.pl` that retrieves the arguments? I tried `current_prolog_flag(argv, ArgList)` and in Linux it includes the command and option flags as part of the argument list, but in Windows, it only provides the arguments themselves. So there are some differences in behavior, depending...

Comment: In SWI-Prolog, there's also the `os_argv` flag. See http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?section=flags#flag:os_argv

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer: just include `--` before `folder1`.

Long answer:

logic1.pl:

```
main :-
    current_prolog_flag(argv, AllArgs),
    append(_, [-- | Args], AllArgs),
    writeln(Args).
```

Run with:

```
$ swipl -s logic1.pl -t main --quiet -- folder1
[folder1]
```